# Select Back Microphone on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, core-audio, audiounit, remoteio

Is there a way for RemoteIO unit to pick up back microphone on iPhone 5 ? I can configure `AVAudioSession` to choose between front microphone or bottom microphone but I can't find a way to select the back Microphone.

The `AVFoundation framework` for sure uses the back microphone for video recording when using the back camera, but I want a way to choose the same using **CoreAudio**. Is that possible ?

Comment: Hi Deepak Sharma could you please give me some idea or code to choose the front microphone or bottom microphone ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Deepak, were you able to find the solution to this? If so would you mind sharing it?

Answer (score 1):

Setting `kAudioSessionProperty_Mode` to `kAudioSessionMode_VideoRecording`with `AudioSessionSetProperty` uses the microphone nearest to the camera, which should be the back microphone. That's if you use the Audio Session Services. `AVAudioSessionModeVideoRecording`if you're using AVFoundation to record. The doc says "Using this mode may result in the system providing appropriate audio signal processing." which I interpet as "we may also use the other mics for noise cancelling".

Answer (score 1):

Use AVAudioSession to get available inputs.  On my iPhone 5 it looks like this.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs);

  "<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x14554400, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone Microphone; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = Back>"
```

Then use one of these inputs to get availableDataSources, like this.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs[0].dataSources);

  "<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145afb00, ID = 1835216945; name = Bottom>",
  "<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145b1870, ID = 1835216946; name = Front>",
  "<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145b3650, ID = 1835216947; name = Back>"
```

Now you can set your preferred data source.

```
AVAudioSessionPortDescription *port = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs[0];
for (AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription *source in port.dataSources) {
    if ([source.dataSourceName isEqualToString:@"Back"]) {
        [port setPreferredDataSource:source error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is supposed to only work on iOS 7 I believe. That is also okay I think.

Comment: what should be the category for using this code, for setting preferred datasource?